# sp_helpdb doesn't return all columns

Tags: sap-ase

When I run `sp_helpdb dbname` in Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise, it returns only the following columns:

> name,db_size,owner,dbid,created,status

And it's not returning the following columns:

> device_fragments,size,usage,created,free     kbytes

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sets are returned however where they are displayed depends on which tool you're using to run the query. If you're using SQL Advantage or ASEISQL, then you need to look in the results and the messages windows to get the full answers. If you're using the command line ISQL then all will be returned together.

It's because some of the results are returned from a select, and some from print messages.

`print "Print hello"`

`select "Select hello"`

Try running the above and you'll hopefully find where each different output is displayed in your tool.

If you're using SQL Advantage see the [SQL Advantage](http://www.sybase.com/content/938/Opt.gif) image here, this shows the options screen in which you can change how your results return. The "Display Print Messages with Results" might help in this case.

Comment: I am using Adaptive Server Enterprise and after running sp_helpdb the Message Windows shows only Execution Time & Result Windows Shows the only Following Columns:      name,db_size,owner,dbid,created,status

Comment: What program are you using to run the query?